# body/html pseudo element not acting on whole document

Tags: html, pseudo-element

Please check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dppJw/8/

I've used a pseudo-element for the `body` (also tried with `html`) and the overlay doesn't go all the way to the end of the document (try scrolling).

How can I have the overlay on the whole document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position:absolute` to `position:fixed`. This will cause the element to stay at the same location, even if the user scrolls.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dppJw/9/**

---

Note: Your current pseudo-element overlaps the body. Add `z-index: -1` if you don't want the text inside the body to be selectable.

Comment: Could I ask *why* changing from `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` does the job?

Comment: `fixed` positions an element relative to the **window**, whereas `absolute` positions an element relative to the closest relatively positioned parent element. The origin of a window doesn't move (with respect to the page). A relatively positioned element, however, can be moved by scrolling/changing offset values.